# Hibernate composite keys and join (one to many)?

Tags: hibernate

We have a reporting table that has a composite key that refers to other tables.  Kind of like this:

```
ReptTable camp_id dev_id date campCnt devCnt
CampTable camp_id ...
DevTable dev_id ...
```

So in the ReptTable camp_id is a foreign key from camptable and dev_id to devtable and in the rept table the composite key is camp_id, dev_id and date.  So with hibernate how do I represent that in the mapping?  The xml for  doesn't seem to allow for the fetch="select/join" attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, I just stumbled upon `<key-many-to-one>` and that seems to solve my problem.